# Converting jpeg images to 16 color bitmap (bmp) images in bulk

Tags: windows, images, image-processing, image-conversion

I have about 10000 jpeg images in a folder and I want to convert all of them into 16 color bitmap bmp images.

It is easy to do for one or two images to open them in paint and save them as 16 color bitmap bmp images but I am dealing with 10000 images here.

Is their any software for Windows OS that could do it with a few clicks?

Comment: I really doubt you can have a 16 bit color map images. What format or container do you need? Paint saves 16 color images, not 16 bit images.

Comment: @Rafael Thanks for pointing it out. Indeed it was a typo. I corrected it to avoid confusion for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really doubt you can have a 16 bit color map images. Paint saves 16 color images, not 16 bit images.

If you need 16 color images (4bit) IrfanView http://www.irfanview.com/ can do that.

1. Open Irfan View
2. Press B (Batch conversion/rename) On that window choose:

a. Batch Conversion.

b. BMP as output format.

c. Advanced

- And there you have the bit depth options.

You can add all files on a folder with a simple click.

Watch out not to override your original files. Choose a different output folder or make a copy of your original images first.